# How to install boot camp without Windows cd?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows, install

I'm trying to install boot camp on my MacBook Pro, problem is I don't have a windows installation disk. Can someone please explain how to install bootcamp without the cd? Please!

Comment: What Windows do you have and what is it on?

Comment: Also, it would be ideal to link to Apple's bootcamp instructions and point out which part you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the physical media and only have an ISO of the Windows CD or do you not even have that? An ISO and an 8GB thumb drive is all you really need. Just launch the Boot Camp app and follow the prompts.

Boot Camp is basically the glue that allows Windows to install on a Mac. And by glue I mean the installation utilities and drivers.

Using Boot Camp without Windows is kind of like using an oil filter without the car to plug it into: it has no function all by itself, it only works in concert with another part. In the case of the oil filter, it needs a car or other vehicle. In the Case of Boot Camp, it needs Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely possible to install Windows without using BootCamp, since all BootCamp does is makes things easier by giving you a handy wizard that does most of grunt work for you (partitioning the drive, drivers, etc.)  So if you need to install Windows in a manner that the BootCamp wizard doesn't support, just don't use it.

All you have to do is shrink your Mac partition in Disk Utility and then create a MS-DOS FAT32 partition.  You can reformat it NTFS during the Windows install later, but creating the FAT32 partition is important.  It's what creates the hybrid MBR on the drive.  If you don't do it, Windows will destroy your Mac partition during the install.

After you've got the partition in place, just pop in whatever media you have Windows on and install it the way you would on a PC.  You can download the BootCamp drivers from Apple's web site.

---

If, however, you mean that you do not have any Windows install media at all, then you misunderstand what BootCamp is for.  BootCamp's only job is to help you install a copy of Windows that you already own onto your Mac.  BootCamp does not contain a copy of Windows, nor does it contain a Windows license.  You are still required to legally purchase a copy of Windows to install on your Mac.